# Agent based NetLogo Code simulation

Tags: netlogo, shortest-path, robotics

Is there any way to implement multiple robots in an environment with obstacles in NetLogo to reach their individual destinations with shortest path?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please be a little more specific. What have you already tried?

Comment: http://www.simulace.info/index.php?title=Maze_Solving_Robot_Simulation

Comment: i have to implement A* in the world for 5 robots going to their destinations avoiding obstacles and others' paths. Is there any way to find best order of them to start first the algorithm?